# How to remove duplication in this line of code?

Tags: java

How do I simplify this code into the simplest form without duplication? Just using simple if/else statements as this is my entry class for programming

```
if (Character.toUpperCase(choosePassOverPed) == 'Y'){
        passengerPoints = passengerPoints + toughCallThresholdPoints;
        if (passengerPoints > pedestrianPoints){
            System.out.println("Fatality Group: PEDESTRIANS");
            System.out.printf("Number of adult fatalities: %d%n", numAdultPedestrians);
            System.out.printf("Number of child fatalities: %d%n", numChildPedestrians);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Fatality Group: OCCUPANTS");
            System.out.printf("Number of adult fatalities: %d%n", numAdultPassengers);
            System.out.printf("Number of child fatalities: %d%n", numChildPassengers);
        }
    }
    else{
        pedestrianPoints = pedestrianPoints + toughCallThresholdPoints;
        if (passengerPoints > pedestrianPoints){
            System.out.println("Fatality Group: PEDESTRIANS");
            System.out.printf("Number of adult fatalities: %d%n", numAdultPedestrians);
            System.out.printf("Number of child fatalities: %d%n", numChildPedestrians);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Fatality Group: OCCUPANTS");
            System.out.printf("Number of adult fatalities: %d%n", numAdultPassengers);
            System.out.printf("Number of child fatalities: %d%n", numChildPassengers);
```

Comment: Put the two repeated print functions into its own method and call the method when needed.

Comment: Check out **[CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)** for feedback / improvement on *existing, working code*. StackOverflow is for *programming problems*.

Answer (score 2):

Simple.

Use *one* set of `printf`, and just set the variables you fill in there in the if/else branches.

In your code example, the ifs don't even do anything but change the first line that is printed.

Answer (score 2):

Only print out of the `if/else`, that will save you much.
You can also take the inner `if/else` out of the outer one.

```
if (Character.toUpperCase(choosePassOverPed) == 'Y') {
    passengerPoints = passengerPoints + toughCallThresholdPoints;
else {
    pedestrianPoints = pedestrianPoints + toughCallThresholdPoints;    
}
if (passengerPoints > pedestrianPoints){
    System.out.println("Fatality Group: PEDESTRIANS");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Fatality Group: OCCUPANTS");
}
System.out.printf("Number of adult fatalities: %d%n", numAdultPassengers);
System.out.printf("Number of child fatalities: %d%n", numChildPassengers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wouldn't actually write it like this but this gets rid of the duplicate code:

```
public void method() {
    // declare variables...

    if (Character.toUpperCase(choosePassOverPed) == 'Y') {
        passengerPoints = passengerPoints + toughCallThresholdPoints;
        checkPoints(passengerPoints, pedestrianPoints, numAdultPedestrians, numChildPedestrians, numAdultPassengers, numChildPassengers);
    } else {
        pedestrianPoints = pedestrianPoints + toughCallThresholdPoints;
        checkPoints(passengerPoints, pedestrianPoints, numAdultPedestrians, numChildPedestrians, numAdultPassengers, numChildPassengers);
    }
}

private static void checkPoints(int passengerPoints, int pedestrianPoints, int numAdultPedestrians, int numChildPedestrians, int numAdultPassengers, int numChildPassengers) {
    if (passengerPoints > pedestrianPoints) {
        System.out.println("Fatality Group: PEDESTRIANS");
        log(numAdultPedestrians, numChildPedestrians);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fatality Group: OCCUPANTS");
        log(numAdultPassengers, numChildPassengers);
    }
}

private static void log(int numAdultPedestrians, int numChildPedestrians) {
    System.out.printf("Number of adult fatalities: %d%n", numAdultPedestrians);
    System.out.printf("Number of child fatalities: %d%n", numChildPedestrians);
}
```

I think there are some concepts in there that could further be abstracted, for example passengerPoints and pedestrians points both behave the same way so may be there is some sort of PersonPoints class that you need.